# Ingress with subdomains

Tags: google-app-engine, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I use Google Cloud for deploy company app.

The goal: every branch deployed on some subdomain(example.com): task-123.example.com, etc.

I copy Cloud DNS namespace to the domain registrar. I pass the static IP address(via `kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "test-static-ip"`) for Ingress and pass it to domain registrar to A record. But I can't understand how to make subdomain works.

Every branch creates Ingress with static IP, but with different URLs for the host.

I made CNAME *.example.com which refers to example.com, but its not works.

Help me, please. Sorry for my English.

Comment: to clarify, you seem to be using the default GCE LB. Are you using a single Ingress with multiple rules or are you using a separate ingress for each subdomain?

Comment: I use Ingress per subdomain(per namespace).

Comment: ok so a different ingress per sub domain and different IP for each one? Do you have A records for each sub domain/ingress resource?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want *.example.com to point to the ingress controller so branch1.example.com and branch2.example.com will both hit the ingress controller. This is achieved with wildcard DNS.

Each branch in your scenario should have its own routing rule (ingress resource) with a host section defined for its specific branch. The ingress controller is updated when a new ingress resource is created and its routing rules then reflect the additional rule. So creating a new branch with a new ingress resource for that host will tell the ingress controller to route traffic for that specific host to a Service specific to that branch. (Or you can define all the branch rules in one go with a fanout ingress - see [ingress-nginx - create one ingress per host? Or combine many hosts into one ingress and reload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52382658/ingress-nginx-create-one-ingress-per-host-or-combine-many-hosts-into-one-ingr/52382878#52382878) )

That's 'how it works'. I'm not sure if that is your question though? It's hard to diagnose the problem you're having. Presumably you have an Ingress, a Service and a Deployment? To help with that I think you'd need to post those and explain (either as an update or a separate question) what behaviour you see (a 404 maybe)?

Comment: I have deployment + service + ingress per branch. Each ingress have the same path rule, but with different host, which depends on branch name. I current situation, when I try to open subdomain - i see long loading. When ping host
PING *** (***): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3

Comment: I guess you are using GCE ingress and not NGINX (https://www.mkubaczyk.com/2017/12/13/kubernetes-ingress-controllers-nginx-gce-google-kubernetes-engine/). There is some debugging advice in their FAQ (https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/blob/master/docs/faq/gce.md). I guess you are doing something like https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/configuring-domain-name-static-ip My impression is your DNS is probably not hitting the IP address for the subdomains. Try it with just one branch no wildcard to narrow down the problem. Also double-check statuses in gcloud console

Comment: Problem fixed by switching to another ip. I use regional ip for ingress, but it works only with global ip. I hame another problem, maybe you know how I can fix it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52934429/ingress-rules-not-works

Answer (score 0):

Making Ingress work with subdomains is made extremely easy with kubernetes. Basically you just define rules for each of your hosts.

Here are specific steps you could follow

1. Point your DNS to your ingress IP address. To do this you will need to setup a global static IP address. In google cloud you can [go here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address) and see how you can set that up
2. Refer that static IP in you ingress annotation
3. Define rules and host mapping, refer to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/configuring-domain-name-static-ip)

Final code will look like this, I am using helm to iterate through my hosts here

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-router
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "your-static-domain"
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: "your-tls-cert"
spec:
  rules:
{{- range $index,$service := .Values.deployments }}
    - host: {{ $service.host }}
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: {{ $service.name }}-service-name
              servicePort: {{ $service.port }}
{{- end }}
```