# Automating wildcard subdomain support for Kubernetes using Helm operator

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress

Here is my use case:
We have a customer, where each of their services has to be available on dedicated subdomain. Naming convention should be `service-name.customerdomain.com`, where `service-name` is the deployed service and `customerdomain.com` is the customer domain. When a new service is created, it should be available **automatically**, i.e. once `service-name` service is deployed into the cluster, it has to be available on `service-name.customerdomain.com`.

I know, this can be achieved **manually** by following steps:

1. Add Ingress controller to the cluster
2. Create wildcard DNS `*.customerdomain.com` and point it to the
   Ingress controller
3. Map subdomain for each running service. For every existing service from the cluster create a separate section into Ingress resource file `ingress.yaml`, e.g.

> ```
> Spec:     
>     rules: 
>     - host: helloworld.awesome-customer.com 
>     http: 
>         paths: 
>         - path: /* 
>         backend: 
>             serviceName: helloworld 
>             servicePort: 8080 
>     - host: nextfineapp.awesome-customer.com 
>     http: 
>         paths: 
>         - path: /* 
>         backend: 
>             serviceName: nextfineapp 
>             servicePort: 8080 
>     - [...]
> ```

4. Add Ingress resource file new `-host` section for each newly
   deployed service
5. Remove Ingress resource file `-host` section for each removed
   service

Basically - I would like to automate steps 4 & 5. I am aware Ingress cannot handle this by itself, however, googling around, it appears that updating `ingress.yaml` file each time a new service is deployed / an existing one is removed can be achieved via [Helm](https://helm.sh/) and its values files.

I would appreciate if a sample solution can be pointed out / described below.

Answer (score 2):

You would generally do this by having a template for the Ingress resource as a part of your base application chart. You can have more than one Ingress object and they will all get muxed at run time to build the routing table for your controller.

Comment: Could you please provide a kind of example / snippet on the proposal. URL to specific solution would work as well.

Comment: You can look at what we do on Activiti. Here's an Activiti cloud example - https://github.com/Activiti/activiti-cloud-charts/tree/master/activiti-cloud-full-example and the readme describes the wildcard DNS setup and how to run. The gateway and keycloak are both being exposed on it. And you can see the templated Ingress resources in their charts - https://github.com/Activiti/activiti-cloud-charts/blob/master/activiti-cloud-gateway/templates/ingress.yaml

Comment: The gitlab helm chart is also based around wildcard DNS - https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/kubernetes/gitlab_chart.html

Comment: An easy way to try it out is deploy something to use nip.io for free wildcard DNS and deploy a couple of services with their ingress hosts as <service name>.<ingress controller IP>.nip.io

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend going with @coderanger's suggestion. If you add the Ingress in a helm chart then it can be controlled via the values.yaml file. This is what the official kubernetes helm charts do. However, it isn't exactly automation of creating the Ingress as the templated Ingress source file is still there. It is templating rather than automating.

For further automation you could look at Jenkins-X expose controller. That would need to be deployed in your cluster and then it would watch what services are deployed and what annotations they have on them to automatically create Ingresses. With this you still need the annotations though as you have to indicate which services to expose and what routing logic to apply to them. If you are using helm your values files end up similar whether using expose controller or putting Ingress resources in the charts.

The Jenkins-X expose controller can also work with wildcard DNS. Actually Jenkins-X uses wildcard DNS and expose controller by default so you could follow one of their guide to see this in action. Because they support this for different platforms their docs can be helpful in seeing how to setup wildcard DNS for different cloud providers e.g. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/continuous-delivery-eks-jenkins-x/

Comment: The above solution somehow changed the focus imo. After additional googling, I was thinking of the following approach, using Helm operator: 1) Once a new Service is deployed in the scope of the cluster, this should be picked up by Helm operator; 2) `ingress.yml` will be updated with a new `-host` section, where service-name and subdomain name will be specified, using the following pattern `service-name.domain.com`; 3) Ingress controller will be rebuild, hence the new service will be available via the newly added subdomain. Does it seem feasible?

Comment: So you are thing maybe you could use (or extend?) the Helm operator to automatically generate/modify Ingresses? I'd be interested in seeing the links that led you to this idea. I assumed (and I guess @coderanger did too) that you were looking to use helm charts that contain ingress yaml files in the usual helm way (like in the official charts).

Comment: To be clear, you are not limited to having only a single ingress yaml file. You can deploy multiple and each specifies a particular rule and the rules will all be applied by the ingress controller. So umbrella helm charts can contain multiple subcharts and each subchart can specify its own ingress rules - when deployed they all get applied. This is actually a feature of ingress - it externalises proxy config.

Comment: On the point about splitting rules across files see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52382658/ingress-nginx-create-one-ingress-per-host-or-combine-many-hosts-into-one-ingr

Comment: I wasn't quite sure if ingress `yaml` file can be updated. I guess your  suggestion above seems to be more feasible. In that particular scenario how the workflow should look like: 1) When a new service is deployed, who will take care and create a new ingress yaml file (Helm operator)? 2) Once the new ingress yaml is created according to resource you posted above the ingress controller will automatically apply the new rule, hence the subdomain will map to the newly created service. Hence, the only unclear part for applying the above workflow is 1). Any ideas how it can be achieved?

Comment: ...and to complete the workflow - in case a service is removed from the cluster, is it possible Helm to remove the corresponding ingress yaml file, hence the rule to be removed from the ingress controller?

Comment: Everything in a helm chart, inc Deployment, Service and Ingress can be applied with 'helm install'. That set of objects installed together is called a release and 'helm delete' can delete a release and all of its objects together. Typically all the resource files in a helm chart are written by a developer and are part of the chart's source code. I'm speaking from a pure helm perspective - I normally work with just helm and not operators.