# Kubernetes deployment style for multiple Ingresses on the same hostname. Are split configurations and single configuration equivalent?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I have two applications: `app1` and `app2`. Each hosted in a separate repository. Each are completely unrelated from one another. I would like to:

1. Serve them from the same hostname, just at different paths.
2. Each application is independent from the other, and so are their deployment scripts.

My current approach is to have one `yaml` file per each application, describing `Deployment`, `Service`, and `Ingress`. I am using nginx to manage the ingress part.

`app1.yaml` contains the following Ingress specification:

```
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
    name: app1-ingress
    annotations:
        kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "1800"
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "1800"
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
            rewrite ^(/apps/app1)$ $1/ redirect; # ZZZ
spec:
    rules:
    - host: myhost
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /apps/app1(/?)(.*)
          backend:
            serviceName: app1-service
            servicePort: 8080
```

`app2.yaml` contains the exact equivalent, with the appropriate entries changed.
When I want to deploy `app1`, I go into its repo and do:

```
kubectl apply -f app1.yaml
```

When I want to deploy `app2`, I go into its repo and do:

```
kubectl apply -f app2.yaml
```

The alternative is to have `app1.yaml` and `app2.yaml` just define the service, and then have an additional file containing the Ingress specification:

```
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
    name: ingress
    annotations:
        kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "1800"
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "1800"
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
            rewrite ^(/apps/.*)$ $1/ redirect; # ZZZ
spec:
    rules:
    - host: myhost
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /apps/app1(/?)(.*)
          backend:
            serviceName: app1-service
            servicePort: 8080
        paths:
        - path: /apps/app2(/?)(.*)
          backend:
            serviceName: app2-service
            servicePort: 8080
```

Assume that I am going to add more and more applications `app3`, `app4` and so on in the future.

**My question is:** *are these two specification styles equivalent, or is it one style preferred for technical or best practices reasons?*

Comment: working with multiple resources, i can say that it is easier for me to have many Ingress resources because when needed i can find the right resource quickly , but if you are not working with helm or kustomize (or something of that sort) changing an annotation in all of the resources will not be easy, so your call.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite opinion based and it is impossible to give an unequivocal answer.

From my experience, it's better to use ingress per one service. For longer period of time it's comfortable - imagine one day you need to add / change some annotations in ingresss related to one specific service or group of services - you will need to divide your ingress into few files. It will create a mess. That's why it's better to keep ingress definitions separated - especially you have apps hosted in different repositories.

Also check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52382658/ingress-nginx-create-one-ingress-per-host-or-combine-many-hosts-into-one-ingr) (It's about hosts, not the paths, but it very similar to your question). You may find here many useful information.